# Ошибка TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable functools._lru_cache_wrapper object

Tags: python

При запуске программы почему-то выдает такую ошибку, и я не понимаю, как ее исправить

```
from functools import lru_cache


def moves(h):
    a, b = h
    return (a + 1, b), (a, b + 1), (a * 2, b), (a, b * 2)


@lru_cache(maxsize=None)

def f(h):
    if sum(h) >= 79:
        return 'end'
    if any(f(x) == 'end' for x in moves(h)):
        return 'win1'
    if all(f(x) == 'win1' for x in moves(h)):
        return 'lose1'
    if any(f(x) == 'lose1' for x in moves(f)):
        return 'win2'
    if all(f(x) == 'win1' or f(x) == 'win2' for x in moves(h)):
        return 'lose2'


for i in range(1, 100):
    h = 7, i
    print(h, f(h))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну а вот это что такое:

```
if any(f(x) == 'lose1' for x in moves(f)):
                                     ^^^
```

Здесь вы передаёте в функцию `moves` кэш-декоратор функции `f` вместо кортежа `h`, как в других местах. Исправьте на `h` и всё заработает.

```
if any(f(x) == 'lose1' for x in moves(h)):
```

Comment: точно, как я не заметила сразу эту ошибку. спасибо большое!